# Find (a) $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^{1/n^2})$ (b) $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n!^{1/n^2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find $$(a) \lim_{n\to\infty}(n^{1/n^2})$$ $$(b) \lim_{n\to\infty}(n!^{1/n^2})$$

for $(a)$

$1\leq n^{1/n^2}\leq n^{1/n} $

$\lim(1) _{n \to \infty}= \lim_{n \to \infty} (n^{1/n}) = 1$

Therefore by [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) required limit for (a) is 1

for $(b)$

$1\leq n!^{1/n^2} < n!^{1/n}$

Since $n!\geq 1$ therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n!^{1/n}) = 1$

hence, by Squeeze theorem again required limit for $(b) = 1$

Is this correct ?
Can anyone suggest quicker methods to solve such question?

**EDIT:**
Apparently,
 $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n!^{1/n}) \to \infty$

My problem here is,

we know $lim_{n\to\infty}(n^{1/n}) = 1$ where $n \in N$

since, $n!\in N$ Why isn't the same true for $lim_{n\to \infty}((n!)^{1/n})$?

Comment: Actually $(n!)^{1/n}\to \infty$ take a look at [Stirling's approximation]  (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(n!)^{1/n}} \neq 1$. In some sense, the factorial "beats" the nth root.

Comment: As you know apparently the limit of $n^{1/n}$, you can use that $n!\leq n^n$ to finish.

Comment: actually, I have this theorem $lim_{n\to\infty}(n^{1/n}) = 1 $
so I applied it here since $n! \in N$

Comment: @VishweshwarTyagi $n^{1/n}\neq (n!)^{1/n}$.

Comment: @Kelenner thanks that will do it

Comment: Regarding your edit: if you desire to apply your theorem to the subsequence $(n!)$, you have to replace it consistently. That would be $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(n!)^{1/n!}}$.

Comment: for the second one, you could consider the limit of log of the function, you can then show that the function is bounded by log(n) / n, and l'hopital would give the limit as zero

Answer (score 1):

Use the logarithm:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(n^{1/n^2})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n^2}
$$
which is known to be $0$. So the original limit is $e^0=1$.

On the other hand, you can easily prove
$$
\frac{\log n}{n^2}\le
\log((n!)^{1/n^2})\le
\frac{n\log n}{n^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

(b) we can use sandwitch theorem as follows:

$1=\lim_{n\to\infty} (n^2)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}\leq (n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty} (n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

remembering the most fundamental limit : $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$